# ISSUE ON NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.course_id

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to create a multiple user model in django. I am a beginner using django and as such not in a position to get the exact result I need.
I got an error when trying to createsuperuser.

Here is my model.py

```
*from django.db import models
from admin_dash.models import Course
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,roll,phone,name,password=None):
        if not roll:
            raise ValueError('You Don't have Permission to do exam')
        user = self.model(
        roll=roll,
        phone=phone,
        name=name
    )
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
  def create_superuser(self,roll,phone,name, password):
       user = self.create_user(roll,phone,name,password=password)
       user.is_admin = True
       user.is_staff=True
       user.save(using=self._db)
       return user
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone= models.CharField(verbose_name='phone number', max_length=12,unique=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)
    roll=models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='roll',unique=True)
    course=models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joind=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joind', auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'roll'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','phone']
    objects = UserManager()
  def __str__(self):
      return self.name
  def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
     return self.is_admin

  def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
     return True*
```

This is My admin.py

```
*from django.contrib import admin
from .import models
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(models.User)*
```

Trying to create a superuser I got the following traceback

```
    *Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.course_id
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\projects\exam-master\accounts\models.py", line 21, in create_superuser
    user = self.create_user(roll,phone,name,password=password)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\projects\exam-master\accounts\models.py", line 16, in create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 924, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1391, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.course_id*
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The foreign key User.course is non-nullable, you need to provide this field for every user you create. Adding the field to `REQUIRED_FIELDS` should make createsuperuser ask for a value for the field

Comment: Hello, lain Shelvington. Please, how do I do that? I did not get your response well. Am I going to create a field in the class User(AbstractBaseUser)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add course field into the REQUIRED_FIELDS of your custom User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    phone= models.CharField(verbose_name='phone number', max_length=12,unique=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True)
    roll=models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='roll',unique=True)
    course=models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joind=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joind', auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'roll'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name','phone', 'course']
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

You also need to change your custom User Manager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone, roll, course, password, name=None):
        if isinstance(course, int):
            course = Course.objects.get(pk=course)

        user = self.model(phone=phone, roll=roll, course=course, name=name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone, roll, course, password, name=None):
        user = self.create_user(phone=phone, roll=roll, course=course, password=password, name=name)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save()
        return user
```

Now when you run the command `python manage.py createsuperuser`, it ask you for a course (you need to insert the value of the primary key of the Course instance you want to associate)

Comment: Hello  lain , I tried to run the code as you have guided me. There is another issue again, bellow is the Traceback:   File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
TypeError: create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'course'

Comment: @FredOriabor you need to make changes to your custom User Manager, i have updated my answer with the full code.

Comment: Thank you so much Redwheelbarow. This code is frustrating me. I got the following error after running the command "python manage.py createsuperuser"  File "C:\Users\freddyparc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 214, in __set__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "User.course" must be a "Course" instance.

Comment: If I may ask should I send the app to you for perusal?

Comment: @FredOriabor i have updated my answer, now you can pass the pk of the course in the command

Comment: It works! Redwheelbarrow, you are too much. I really appreciate you so much, in fact you really made my day. Pls, don't see me as "Oliver Twist" I'll be glad if you can still help me in the area of Entity Relation. In this particular project, a student in a class (i.e J.S.S 1) should be able to attend examination for J.S.S 1 in a particular term and academic session. Note: In my country we have "Academic session, in academic session we have terms, in a term we have 1st, 2nd and 3rd term. Student should be a able to select field for class, subject ,academic session & term and print result.